# How can I delete portion of data in python pandas dataframe imported from csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to take the days out of the column Days_To_Maturity. So instead of Days 0, it will just be 0. I have tried a few things but am wondering if there is a easy way to do this built into python. Thanks

```
In[12]:
from pandas import *
XYZ = read_csv('XYZ')
df_XYZ = DataFrame(XYZ)
df_XYZ.head()

Out[12]:
       Dates    Days_To_Maturity    Yield
0    5/1/2002    Days 0                 0.00
1    5/1/2002    Days 1                 0.06
2    5/1/2002    Days 2                 0.12
3    5/1/2002    Days 3                 0.18
4    5/1/2002    Days 4                 0.23
5 rows × 3 columns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explore the possibility of using `.str` method, either you can extract the numbers using `regex`, or take a slice `.str.slice`, or like in this example, replace `days` with a empty string:

```
In [109]:

df.Days_To_Maturity.str.replace('Days ','').astype(int)
Out[109]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
Name: Days_To_Maturity, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Or `split` instead of `replace`, e.g. `df["Days_To_Maturity"].str.split().str[1].astype(int)`.

Comment: Just added three other alternative while you are commenting, only forget to think about `split()`. :D

Comment: Thank you CT Zhu, helpful as always.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution you are looking for is in the "converters" option of the read_csv function of pandas.  From help(pandas.read_csv):

`converters: dict. optional
    Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels.`

So instead of `read_csv('XYZ')` you would make a custom converter:

`myconverter = { 'Days_To_Maturity': lambda x: x.split(' ')[1] }
read_csv('XYZ',converter=myconverter)`

This should work. Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: Hi there. Very helpful! Another great way to do it and I was not aware of the ability to alter data upon import. Thanks much.